# Using get_serving_url() for a image stored as blob property in datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a datastore storing images as a blob property. I want to use get_serving_url to serve images on the fly.

```
    def urlserve(self):
         return images.get_serving_url(str(self.key.urlsafe()),350)
```

It gives me a URL like

```
http://localhost:8097/_ah/img/ahBkZXZ-cmFqaW5pbmF0aW9uciYLEglpbWFnZWxpc3QiDWRlZmF1bHRfaW1hZ2UMCxIDSW1nGKkHDA=s350
```

But I can't able to serve using that page.

So I could only use blobstore image to do this, if so do i need to create a blobstore for my image and store the blobreferenceproperty in my datastore? Or is there better way?

Comment: Yes, store your images in the blobstore and store the serving_url and the blob reference in the datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `db` then you should store the `blob_info.key()` in the `blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty`, otherwise if you're using the `ndb` then you should store the `key` in the `ndb.BlobKeyProperty`.

For the image serving URL you don't have to calculate it all the time, but you could simply store the value of it to your Model at the same time that you are storing the `BlobKey`.