# how to display images from the ndb datastore using data URI scheme (via passing data to template and not having to make another request)

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

I store a thumbnail image as a blob property of my entity. I am able to serve the images just fine as described here: [Displaying Blob Images in Python (App Engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550362/displaying-blob-images-in-python-app-engine)

This however requires making another get request and fetching the image by id from the ndb. Since I already have the original entity available at the time I render the img tag with appropriate href attribute, would there exist a way to render the image inline using the [Data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)?

I read the documentation for google images API but there doesn't seem to be a method that would render my image to the required format to include it as a string. I also googled quite extensively but somehow everyone is suggesting the solution for rendering images from the datastore as referenced above. To my mind being able to render the images using the uri scheme would not only save datastore get requests (would most likely be fetched from memcache but still) but most importantly would save visitors of my page a round trip across the ocean which would speed up the serving of the page quite considerably.

Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: You would have to implement it yourself it's not hard. Have you read the disadvantages of that approach.  I personally wouldn't do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Tim! I was not aware there were any disadvantages to this approach. Just read up a little bit on Wikipedia about this and it seems that the biggest disadvantage would be that there is no way to cache the image?

Comment: Correct, also if the image appears in multiple places/pages the browser can't cache it.

Comment: I use BlobProperties to store images and thumbnails for a reasonably image intensive site.  Everything is also cached by memcache. This all works well, though the sites traffic is not sufficient for me to consider moving images to GCS, though if it did grow significantly I could, but it would probably have to grow 5 times to make it worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the image service and the images will be served from a high speed image serving service that'll probably be closer to your end users in any case then anything you could arrange yourself in GAE.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions

```
get_serving_url(blob_key, size=None, crop=False, secure_url=None)
```

> Returns a URL that serves the image.
>
> This URL format allows dynamic resizing and cropping, so you don't
>   need to store different image sizes on the server. **Images are served
>   with low latency from a highly optimized, cookieless infrastructure.**

This also avoids another hit to the database, as you'd store the URL and serve that to the user.

Comment: In my current implementation I am not storing the image as a Blob but rather as an ndb.BlobProperty of the entity. If I understand it correctly, in order to be able to use get_serving_url() I would need to store the image as a separate Blob entity? (once I obtain the serving url I could then store the url on my original entity as the url should not change for the entire life of the referenced image?)

Comment: A quick look at similar questions says that you can't generate it for such entities. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897836/using-get-serving-url-for-a-image-stored-as-blob-property-in-datastore/14899788#14899788 However it should also be the case that storing your images in the blobstore/GCS would be significantly cheaper, rather then using the datastore. For the second part of your comment, yes, the URL will persist until you call delete_serving_url.